# Different methods give different answers for problem about pulley being lifted by a force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

The situation is as in the diagram below. The pulley and the rope are considered massless, and we ignore friction between the pulley and the rope. The force $F$ is $424 N$. We want to find the acceleration of both blocks. If we apply Newton's second law to the whole system, we should get:

$$424 - 30g = 30a \rightarrow a = \frac{13}{3},$$

so the whole system is accelerating up with $a = \frac{13}{3}$. Because the two blocks are connected by the rope, in the non-inertial reference frame of the pulley, the two blocks have equal and opposite accelerations $\alpha$, so by Newton's second law applied to each block:

$$T - 20g = 20(\frac{13}{3} - \alpha)$$
$$T - 10g = 10(\frac{13}{3} + \alpha)$$

Solving the simultaneous equations gives $T = 188.44 N$. However, this contradicts applying Newton's second law to the pulley (the pulley has negligible mass):

$$424 - 2T = 0 \rightarrow T = 212 N$$

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that you assume that the acceleration of the pulley is the same as the center of mass. But this is not true (do you see why?). So when you change to the frame of the pulley, you're using the wrong acceleration.

Comment: Actually, I haven't learnt about centres of mass yet. But your comment sounds reasonable and I believe you are correct. Thank you.

Comment: I'll try to formulate it into a proper answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so the whole system is accelerating up with $=\frac{13}{3}$.

This sentence is not completely clear - if the *whole system* accelerates at this rate, does that refer to the pulley, the blocks, or something else? Which part of the system is supposed to accelerate at a rate of $\frac{13}{3} \approx 4.3$ m/s$^2$? I think that this small lack of clarity is what causes the entire confusion.

You correctly say that the total force on the pulley must be zero as it is massless, so $T = 212$ N. Given that this is the tension, we can find the acceleration on each of the blocks using Newton's second law. For the left block, we have
$$ 20 \text{kg} \cdot a_L = -20 \text{kg} \cdot g + T,$$
where I have used the convention that upwards acceleration is positive. Solving this, we get
$$ a_L = \frac{T}{20 \text{kg}} - g \approx 0.8 \text{ m/s}^2.$$
For the right block, we find
$$ a_R = \frac{T}{10 \text{kg}} - g \approx 11.4 \text{ m/s}^2.$$

Now we've found the acceleration of the two blocks. How fast does the pulley accelerate? Well, the length of the rope must be constant, so in the frame of the pulley the acceleration of block L must be equal and opposite to that of block R. Let $a_P$ be the acceleration of the pulley; we must then have
$$a_L - a_p = - (a_R - a_p),$$
or $$a_p = \frac{a_L + a_R}{2} = 6.1 \text{ m/s}^2.$$

How about the "system acceleration" of $4.3$ m/s$^2$? Can we find this somewhere? Well, it turns out that this is the acceleration of the center of mass; namely

$$\frac{20 \text{kg} \cdot a_L + 10 \text{kg} \cdot a_R}{30 \text{kg}} = 4.3 \text{m/s}^2.$$

Note, however, that *no physical part* of the system actually accelerates at 4.3 m/s$^2$. This only represents the mass-weighted "average" acceleration.

Comment: Acceleration unit $~m/s^2$

Comment: Thanks @Eli! Fixed now. :)